# How do i get social media icons to align in footer?

Tags: html, css, icons, alignment, footer

I am currently working on my new site www.jobreviewboard.com and I am having issues aligned the social media icons in the footer. if you go on the site you will see what I mean with the twitter icon. this is what I have in my footer now. any help would be appreciated!:) I have tried adding a main div for all 4...no luck. tried separate divs..no luck...tried no div...no luck

```
 <footer>
 <font style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:10.5pt;"><div style="margin-top:-20px;margin-left:20px;">Copyright © 2014 Job Review Board. All Rights Reserved. Love or Hate your Job? Review it here!

 <div>
 <a href="http://linkedin.com" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;border:0px;">
 <img src="../icones/linkedin.png" border="0" style="margin-left:700px;margin-top:8px"/>

 <a href="http://googleplus.com" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;border:0px;">
 <img src="../icones/gplus.png" border="0" style="margin-left:710px:margin-top:8px;"/>

 <a href="http://googleplus.com" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;border:0px;">
 <img src="../icones/fb.png" border="0" style="margin-left:720px:margin-top:8px;"/>

 <a href="http://googleplus.com" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;border:0px;">
 <img src="../icones/twitter.png" border="0" style="margin-left:860px;margin-top:-200px;"/>
 </div>

 </div></font>

 </footer>
```

Comment: take out the font tags for a start they're deprecated. put in closing </a> tags after the imgs. you have too many </div> tags and why do you have div tags anyway? the footer is a div take them out. put your style in a stylesheet.

Comment: see edited answer with updated fiddle. please accept thanks :)

Comment: did you see the fiddle? it includes your formatting

Comment: i have to go over to my sisters for about 2 and a half hours. i will help you later if you are still stuck.

Comment: set padding-top to 0 in p and then leave it so i can see what it looks like take oyt the p2 you don't need it. in the ul_social icons put in margin-right:8px; that will move the icons over a bit

Comment: decrease the margin-top in the li_social from -29 to -25

Comment: you are the best! its all aligned now!:) I juust want to move the icons a bit to the left now so it center with the square above

Comment: thank you! just increase the margin-right to about 12px and that should do the trick even 10 might do

Comment: ok I got it now!:) changed it from margin right 8px to margin right 14px and now its good! only weird thing though is when I tried 15 or above it would put one of the icons out of place

Comment: so glad you got it! :) knew we'd get there!

Comment: thanks to you only! thanks a million again!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the elements in a list (ul li) and then style your list with

```
list-style: none;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;  
float:right;
position: relative;
```

here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K6k4p/3/) of your footer

Comment: hey, thank you for the prompt reply. I will try this is a bit and let you know how it works out. Im kind of lost by what you mean when you say put the elements in a list and then style with:(

Comment: put the style in a seperate css style sheet or in the header between <style> </style> tags

Comment: hey whats going on with the jfiddle link, I saw it yesterday but its not there today?:S

Comment: @SashaEssentialzJevremovic its in the answer

Comment: hey I see it now:) ive put it in my style.css and changed the footer with the code that you have provided me with but now the google overlaps the twitter and the linked in overlaps the facebook logo. and the copyright line is on the bottom on the footer. can you please look at jobreviewboard.com so you can what im talking about:)

Comment: update it so that the max-width:25%; is only in ul.social_icons like so http://jsfiddle.net/K6k4p/4/ take out the padding-top in the p section and take out the border-top in the footer

Comment: hey ive updated it now and it looks almost exactly how I want it to look. I was wondering if I can move the icons over to the left a bot so its below in the middle of the box on top and if I can move up the copyright line a bit to align with icons cuz when I try to change either <p> or ul social icons class both get moved a bit :S

Answer (score 1):

Try this for existing structure asked in question

```
font > div > div {
text-align: center;
}
div > a {
display: inline-block;
}

div > a > img{margin:5px}
```